# Using Filters to Restrict JSP Access?

Tags: ajax, jsp, url, servlets, servlet-filters

Im using a javascript call from a JSP to login using an AJAX call and the prototype framework for the server side request, I set up a filter to intercept all requests so that I can either redirect to the login page or proceed.

The problem Im having is that if you type the path into the URL in the browser to go to a different page, theres no way of filtering this before the page loads because its not an AJAX request and in some cases there isnt an HTTPWebRequest until a button is pressed on the page..

What would be the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` is ASP.NET/C# specific. In JSP/Servlet it's `HttpServletRequest`. Please pay attention to the proper class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are not utilizing the Java EE provided container managed authentication. It would namely take this automatically into account when properly configured.

With a homegrown authentication system, the normal practice is to put the logged-in user as an attribute in the session scope so that the remnant of your code can intercept on that, so also the [servlet filters](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

Assuming that your login method look like this:

```
User user = userService.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
}

// ...
```

Then you could just do as follows in a filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
    }
}
```

Map this filter on an URL pattern which covers the secured pages, e.g. `/app/*` or something.

Comment: I would use a form based login if possible, but Im not sure how or if its possible to set up realms and so forth without using an app server? All users are coming from a database and would have roles from there as well, so is there a way utilize this in the deployment descriptor or something? I couldnt find anything online.

Comment: Without an app server? How are you running the webapp then?

Comment: I apologize, I reread that and figured youd ask me that, sorry, I meant without configuring users and realms and so forth on the app server, instead checking the username and password against a user in a database...

Comment: If you don't want to configure a realm, then you'll just have to homegrow it all yourself. I assume that you're fully aware that you can perfectly create a realm against an existing database?

Comment: yeah, i have never done that though! thank you very much for your  answer, im going to try and get this filter working i think!